# Try lock mutex or wait until unlocked

Tags: c#, .net

I have a multinstance application running on a single computer. I would like to achieve the following pseudocode in C#:

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "SomeMutex");
while (true)
{
    if (CheckIfCanDoSomething())
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
        {
            // I am the first instance that can do the task
            DoSomething();
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            // Some other instance was first, wait until it has finished
            mutex.WaitUntilUnlockedWithoutLockingIt();
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have multiple instances of one application, that is checking constantly whether some conditions are met (`CheckIfCanDoSomething`) to do something (`DoSomething`). The problem is that when the conditions are met, only one instance of the application should do this task. The `CheckIfCanDoSomething` method will return `true` until the `DoSomething` task has been completed.

How could I achieve the `mutex.WaitUntilUnlockedWithoutLockingIt()` logic?

Comment: how do you implement multinstance locking? DataBase, File, Registry?

Comment: @eocron Named mutex

Comment: your pseudocode not acquiring lock

Comment: @eocron It is: if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))

Answer (score 1):

Well, you obviously has error in your pseudocode. Actually I would have created Mutext method extension which will describe critical section:

```
public static void InCritical(this Mutex m, Action action)
{
    m.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    finally
    {
        m.ReleaseMutext()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "SomeMutex");
while (true)
{
    if (CheckIfCanDoSomething())
    {
        mutex.InCritical(()=>
        {
            if (CheckIfCanDoSomething())
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        });
        //at this point just recheck in while(true)
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good answer to call CheckIfCanDoSomething twice, but unfortunately the call to `DoSomething` must be done as fast as possible after `CheckIfCanDoSomething` returns true. And in my case it is a HTTP request, so I can't afford such delay.

Comment: Well, then you have two options: 1) remove second check and don't care about doing DoSomething() two times in a row from time to time which can potentialy lead to serious undebugable errors. 2) cache the value of CheckIfCanDoSomething() globaly, across applications.

Comment: I will try to use shared memory (ex. MemoryMappedFile) for such caching, it should be fast enough.

Comment: Dont forget to lock cache of CheckIfCanDoSomething() in Read/Write matter. So you accidently don't write in it in middle of job. It will be tricky one problem =)